# Solve can't solve an ellipse equation

Tags: equation-solving

The outputs of

```
Clear[x, y]
Solve[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}, x]
Solve[{2*(1 - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20}, x]
```

are `{}` and `{{x -> 0}, {x -> 4}}`. How to make Mathematica find a solution for the `Solve[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}, x]`?
The line `Solve[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}, {x, y}]` outputs `{{x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> 4, y -> 1}}` correctly.

There are no error messages. Using Mathematica version 11.3.0.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. x86, 64-bit.

Comment: `Solve@Reduce[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}, x] ` yields `{{x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> 4, y -> 1}} `

Comment: `Solve[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}, x, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> 1]`

Comment: Also, `Solve[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}, x, {y}]` or `Solve[Eliminate[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}, y], x]`

Comment: Also  `Solve[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Solve[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}, {x , y}]
(*{{x -> 4, y -> 1}, {x -> 0, y -> 1}}*)
```

Comment: This is the Akku14's answer in the comment.

Comment: @user64494 No it isn't. My versions solve for two(!) parameters `x,y`

Comment: ulrich neumann:If you look in the documentation you will see that `Solve[{sys}]` finds a solution in all the variables from `sys`. The results of `Solve[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}]`  and `Solve[{2*(y - 3)^2 + 3*(x - 2)^2 == 20, y == 1}, {x , y}]` are the same.